# IdentityServer3 rejecting responsetypes that appear in openid "wellknown" configuration

Tags: c#, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am trying to wade my way through learning IdentityServer so that I can implement single sign-on at my workplace. I have a POC service running locally and when I request the configuration, this is the configuration that displays:

```
{"issuer":"https://localhost:44345/core","jwks_uri":"https://localhost:44345/core/.well-known/jwks","authorization_endpoint":"https://localhost:44345/core/connect/authorize","token_endpoint":"https://localhost:44345/core/connect/token","userinfo_endpoint":"https://localhost:44345/core/connect/userinfo","end_session_endpoint":"https://localhost:44345/core/connect/endsession","check_session_iframe":"https://localhost:44345/core/connect/checksession","revocation_endpoint":"https://localhost:44345/core/connect/revocation","introspection_endpoint":"https://localhost:44345/core/connect/introspect","frontchannel_logout_supported":true,"frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"scopes_supported":["openid","profile","email","roles","offline_access"],"claims_supported":["sub","name","family_name","given_name","middle_name","nickname","preferred_username","profile","picture","website","gender","birthdate","zoneinfo","locale","updated_at","email","email_verified","role"],"response_types_supported":["code","token","id_token","id_token token","code id_token","code token","code id_token token"],"response_modes_supported":["form_post","query","fragment"],"grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","client_credentials","password","refresh_token","implicit"],"subject_types_supported":["public"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256"],"code_challenge_methods_supported":["plain","S256"],"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_post","client_secret_basic"]}
```

As part of this, you can see:

```
"response_types_supported":["code","token","id_token","id_token token","code id_token","code token","code id_token token"]
```

However, when I send a request to the service, with responseType=id_token in the url, I get the error message:

**The authorization server does not support the requested response type.**

I have tried other responseType values but still get this error message.

I am basically a beginner at web security and IdentityServer, so I am sure I am missing something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty stupid. All of the examples online I have looked at for IdentityServer show the parameter as responseTypes (camel case). I think these examples must have all been done against an older version of the platform.

The correct parameter name to send is response_types.

Comment: Where is this? Is it in the docs somewhere, so one can fix it? the docs are open source

Comment: Show me an example.

Answer (score 1):

The list of possible parameters that you can send to the authorization endpoint are listed on the following websites :

- OpenId RFC : http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest
- Identity server doc : https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html

The correct parameter is "*response_type*" and not "*response_types*" :)